# Elasticsearch- query_shard_exception; [has_parent] no join field has been configured

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana

Whenever i try to query has_parent/has_child scenario, getting this in response:
Error: "[has_parent] no join field has been configured"

Expecting the child objects

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the field you are trying to run a has_child query is of the type join:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "my_join_field": { 
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "question": "answer" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

If thats not the problem add the mappings/settings/queries to your question.